# Wireframes in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

`glPolygoneMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)` is ON, and how can I get wireframe at this situation? Is there any way to get wireframe rendering without switch Polygone Mode to `GL_LINE`?

Comment: any answers with mysterious shaders (or black magic with alpha-depth-blend) are accepted

Comment: glPolygoneMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL) is ON at all time of render scene, I can't switch it off

Comment: Could you tell us why you can't switch it off?

Answer (score 18):

```
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
```

Fill fills it... you want lines.

EDIT:
Remember, you can always put it back to fill when you're done, like this

```
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
 // add polygons here
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );
```

Comment: @infra Care to explain why not?

Comment: @infra `GL_FILL` will fill in the polygon. No questions asked. You can't avoid that. If you want to do wireframe, you must to `GL_LINE`. That's the mechanism openGL provides for doing wireframes!

Comment: updated question: "Is there any way to get wireframe rendering without switch Polygone Mode to GL_LINE?"

Answer (score 5):

From your question I assume you have some huge middleware, and have only access to shaders, am I right ?

In this case, create in your vertex shader a varying called, for instance, vertexID :

```
varying float vertexID; # in GLSL <= 3, or
out float vertexID;     # in GLSL 4
```

and assign it the built-in gl_VertexID :

```
vertexID = (float)gl_VertexID;
```

This way, you'll get access to gl_VertexID from the fragment shader, but interpolated ! This is great because it will be, for instance, 2 at one vertex, 3 at the neighbour, and 2.5 inbetween.

So you just have to check if vertexID is close to 2 (resp. 3) : if so, you're close to an edge. That should be good enough for visualisation & debug.

```
in float vertexID; # or
varying float vertexID;

// blabla

if (fract(vertexID) < 0.1){
    outcolor = vec4(1,0,0,0); # in glsl 4
}
```

Note that you'll get only 2 edges of each triangle this way. And maybe some will be ver thin ( if one vertexID is 2 and the other 1000, the 0.1 zone is little ).

Comment: yes, you are right: system is shader-oriented (means only programmable pipeline). And your answer is very close, thank you!

Comment: but it seems odd - to add this shader to all objects at scene :(

Comment: @infra I don't get your last comment, you can set it only for one mesh if you want. I mean, if your system allows it.

Comment: @Calvin1602 you suggest to interpolate (more or less) random integral numbers over your fragment. `fract(vertexID) < 0.1` will be true for pixels near the vertices but not generally near the edge and depending on the actual numbers also all over the rendered primitive. That does not have to do too much with rendering a wireframe, right?

Comment: @axxel Not generally, indeed. But often, IDs are contiguous so it works. Nevertheless, it's an ugly hack, I never said it would be perfect =)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, but I guess that you want to render both the filled polygon AND the wireframe. Turns out that's not so trivial. A classic way to solve the problem is:

```
glPolygonMode( ... GL_FILL);
draw();
glPolygonOffset( param1, param2 );
glPolygonMode( ... GL_LINE );
draw();
```

but this is not without problems, such as figuring out the values to pass to `glPolygonOffset`, etc.